# Show current class belongs to which module in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I have opened multiple modules inside the same IntelliJ window. While I'm navigating through the classes, I want to know particular class belongs to which module.

Currently I'm placing the mouse cursor on the class name tab. Then it shows a path to the class as a tool-tip, then I figure out that class is coming from which module.

Is there any other way I can quickly view the module name, a class is belongs to?

Comment: Not really answer your question but using "Jump to Navigation Bar" action (default binding to `ctrl-escape` on macOS) can be a bit faster than hovering the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Module name is displaying **in the Title Bar** of the IntelliJ window

Comment: This is not true anymore for the most recent UI